# Java Exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I have some problems with the code every time I try to compile the exception `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` appears. Here is the code with the problem I really don't know what I have done wrong. In the code I try to split a `string` using some conditions, the `string` represent a polynomial.

```
int[] coef1= new int[20];
for(i=0;i<polinom.length()+1;i++){
    if(polinom.charAt(i)=='+' )
         c=polinom.charAt(i+1);
    else{
       if(polinom.charAt(i)=='^'){
            v=Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(polinom.charAt(i+1)));
            coef1[v]=Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c));
            System.out.print(coef1[v]);

       }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<polinom.length()+1;i++){
    if(polinom.charAt(i)=='-' )
         c=polinom.charAt(i+1);
    else{
       if(polinom.charAt(i)=='^'){
            v=Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(polinom.charAt(i+1)));
            coef1[v]=-Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c));
            System.out.print(coef1[v]);

        }
    }
}
```

The exception is here `if(polinom.charAt(i)=='+' )`

Comment: post the stack trace would be much easier to track where exception was thrown

Comment: I agree with @Ramanlfc this error can be rather easy to resolve if we know the line it is occurring at.

Comment: In the second line here you are using ``for(i=0;i<polinom.length()+1;i++){``. That ``+1`` should be ``-1``.

Comment: for(i=0;i<polinom.length()+1;i++) you are running loop with length + 1.

Comment: The problem is that nothing works I changed the +1 with -1 but the exception still appears

Comment: This site has numerous java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException questions already. It also has a search function. Did you use it?

Comment: When I use the debug process on the project  at the last  character of this type '^'  the exception appears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace all your

```
for(i=0;i<polinom.length()+1;i++){
```

with

```
for(i=0;i<polinom.length()-1;i++){
```

As indices are 0-based and you use `polinom.charAt(i+1)`, `i+1` should never be equal (nor greater) than `polinom.length`.

Or if you want ot be able to test until the last character of you string (for other processing), you can ensure that `polinom.charAt(i+1)` gets never triggered if `i == polinom.length() - 1`, just add a test before processing your stuff:

```
for(i=0;i<polinom.length();i++){ // not using -1, looping to the end of the string
    if(polinom.charAt(i)=='+' && i < polinom.length() - 1) // checking that no exception will be thrown
        c=polinom.charAt(i+1);
    else{
       if(polinom.charAt(i)=='^' && i < polinom.length() - 1){ // same
           v=Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(polinom.charAt(i+1)));
           coef1[v]=-Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c));
           System.out.print(coef1[v]);
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second line here you are using

```
for(i=0;i<polinom.length()+1;i++){
```

That `+1` should be `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the variable `polinom` is a String.

Your're looping beyond the end of the string:

```
for(i=0;i<polinom.length()+1;i++)
```

It should be

```
for(i=0;i<polinom.length()-1;i++)
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as X.L.Ant, if you have nothing new, so no need to copy paste, I think it is better to have something new.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil: you're right but I saw that answer only after having posted mine.

Comment: OK, It was just a suggestion to have a unique answer.